# Computing $ \int \frac{du}{dt}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

If $u=u(x(t),t)$ how do I compute $\displaystyle \int \frac{du}{dt}dt$ ?

Is it as simple as it seems at first glance or do I have to use the fact that

$$\frac{du}{dt}=u_t+\frac{dx}{dt}u_x$$

Comment: It is simple the integral is $u(t)$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{du}{dt} dt=u+C$$

follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus.  The derivative of the anti-derivative is the integrand $\frac{du}{dt}$, while the derivative of the right-hand side is also $\frac{du}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done as you have pointed out:

$$\int \frac{du}{dt} dt = \int ( u_t \, dt + u_x \, dx) = \int du $$

Answer (score 0):

The notation $u=u(x(t),t)$ is confusing.  Let's write that as $v=u(x(t),t)$. Then we'll use $u_1$ and $u_2$ for the partial derivatives with respect to the first and second arguments. The chain rule then says
\begin{align}
dv & = u_1\,dx + u_2\,dt \\[8pt]
& = u_1(x(t),t)x'(t)\,dt + u_2(x(t),t)\,dt
\end{align}
We want
$$
\int \frac{dv}{dt}\,dt = \int \Big( u_1(x(t),t)x'(t) + u_2(x(t),t) \Big)\,dt.
$$